# Forcing a BaseAdapter to update it's views when AsyncTask is done

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, baseadapter

Ok, so my approach is something like this. I am decoding locally stored encrypted and serialized Objects in an `AsyncTask` in an `Activity`. The `Activity` uses a `BaseAdapter` (HistoryAdapter) for the data to display. The `AsyncTask` shows a `ProgressDialog` until decoding is done. When `onProgressUpdate()` is first called, the `ProgressDialog` is cancelled. So far, so good. Next, in `onProgressUpdate()`, the HistoryAdapter is notified of the changes in the common way, triggering it's `getView()` method. In the HistoryAdapter's `getView()`, a second `AsyncTask` is run to modify the created `convertView` and set the data onto the `View`.

Here is where it all fails on me. I inflate the final layout in `onProgressUpdate()`, and set properties and data on `convertView` just fine here. The changes just don't show, even though all the data is set...

So, the `AsyncTask` in HistoryAdapter in itself in fact works perfectly, the changes are just not visible. I tried numurous suggestions mentioned on SO, like invalidating `convertView`, passing a reference to the `ListView` and using `invalidateViews()` (causes an eternal loop but no visible changes, which makes sense).

I really want this, because I really don't want to load the layout with image placeholders before data is available. That I got working, but looks nasty and like the easy way out. So I need the `ListView` to update (add the item) only when progress is done. Any ideas?

EDIT: to clarify: the data is set on the adapter in just the right time. The problem is, the adapter creates a blank `View` (placeholder) first (don't know any other way, otherwise you will get a NullPointerException in getView), then this `View` is inflated / replaced with another `View` in `onProgressUpdate()`. The second `View` is the one who should be visible. This works somewhat, because I can get and set properties on the newly inflated View. The changes are just not visible, and I am still seeing the blank, initially created View. I want to update the ListView on each added item, not when all items are done loading...

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {  
        //convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.history_list_item_holo_dark, null);  
        convertView =  mInflater.inflate(R.layout.blank, parent, false); // CHEAT: LOAD BLANK/ EMPTY LAYOUT
        HistoryHolder item  = history.get(position);
        new AsyncRequest(convertView, position).execute(item);
    }       
    this.parent = parent;
    return convertView;
}//end method

static class ViewHolder {       
    TextView TITLE;
    TextView SUMMARY;
    TextView DATE;
    ImageView CONTACT_ICON;
    ImageView OPTIONS_ICON;
    ImageView TYPE_ICON;
}//end class

private class AsyncRequest extends AsyncTask<HistoryHolder, View, View> {
    ViewHolder holder           = null;
    String title                = "";
    String summary              = "";
    String date                 = "";
    long id                     = 0;
    private View convertView    = null;
    private String type         = "";
    private int position        = -1;

    public AsyncRequest(View superView, int position){
        this.convertView = superView;
        this.position = position;
    }//end constructor

    @Override
    protected View doInBackground(HistoryHolder... item) {
        Thread.currentThread().setName(getClass().getSimpleName()); 

        if (item[0].TYPE.equals("log")){
            //massive decrypting going on here 50-100 ms
            //values like title and summray set here
        }
        if (item[0].TYPE.equals("sms")){
            //massive decrypting going on here 50-100 ms
            //values like title and summray set here
        }
        publishProgress(convertView);
        return convertView;
    }// end method      

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(View... view) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(view);
    }// end method

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(View result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (!MathUtils.isEven(position)){
            result .setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.darker)); //this works as expected, list items vary in color
        } else {
            result .setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.medium_dark));
        } //this works as expected, list items vary in color
        result      = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.history_list_item_holo_dark, parent, false);
        result.setTag(id);
        holder                  = new ViewHolder();
        holder.TITLE            = (TextView)    result .findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.SUMMARY          = (TextView)    result .findViewById(R.id.summary);
        holder.DATE             = (TextView)    result .findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.CONTACT_ICON     = (ImageView)   result .findViewById(R.id.icon);
        holder.TYPE_ICON        = (ImageView)   result .findViewById(R.id.type);
        holder.OPTIONS_ICON     = (ImageView)   result .findViewById(R.id.options);         
        holder.OPTIONS_ICON.setFocusable(false);
        holder.OPTIONS_ICON.setTag(id);         

        holder.TITLE.setText(title); //this change doesnt show
        holder.SUMMARY.setText(summary); //and so on

        result .setTag(holder);
    }//end method
}//end inner class
```

And I know I could modify my AsynTask and that I don't need to pass reference to the View in so many places, but then again, it's code in progress. Simplified example...

**EDIT**

Okay, so it seems my approach was poor to begin with, resulting in the need to have a `AsyncTask` in my `HistoryAdapter`. I adressed a few issues to resolve this.

1. Based on @Delyan 's suggestion, I decided it was good to load/ decrypt data before it is actually needed. I am using a `PropertyChangeListener` for this. This implements a `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` so that it get's notified of changes to the data I need. Changes are then propagated to any interested listeners. The data is decrypted on application start and stored in a global variable, which is accesible throughout the application. See this as the 'memory cache' he referred to.
2. Based on the comments and on the accepted answer, decrypting now is done in the background, so there is no longer a need for `AsyncTasks`.
3. To further optimise the performance of my adapter, I am storing images needed for the `ListView` in a `SparseArray`, so they are only created and stored once. Don't use  a `HashMap` for this! Furthermore, the images are only created for the current `View` if they aren't already in a `HashMap` (images aren't unique).

---

```
public class HistoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter{    

    private static Context context                  = ApplicationSubclass.getApplicationContext_(); 
    private Contacts contacts                       = Contacts.init(context);
    private SparseArray<Drawable> c_images          = new SparseArray<Drawable>();
    private HashMap<Long, Drawable> contact_imgs    = new HashMap<Long, Drawable>();
    private ArrayList<HistoryHolder> history;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public HistoryAdapter(Context context) {
        HistoryAdapter.context = context;
        mInflater   = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }//end constructor

    ...

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
        final HistoryHolder item = history.get(position);

        Drawable d = null;
        if (c_images.get(position) == null){
            if (!contact_imgs.containsKey(item.CONTACT_ID)){
                if (item.IN_CONTACTS && item.CONTACT_ID != 0 && item.CONTACT_ID != -1){ 
                    Bitmap photo = contacts.getContactPhotoThumbnailByContactId(item.CONTACT_ID);
                    if (photo != null){
                        d = Convert.bitmapToDrawable(context, photo, 128, 128);
                    } else {
                        d = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);
                }
                } else {
                    d = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);              
                }
                contact_imgs.put(item.CONTACT_ID, d); 
            }
        }
        c_images.put(position, contact_imgs.get(item.CONTACT_ID));

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView             = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.history_list_item_holo_dark, null);            
            holder                  = new ViewHolder();
            holder.POSITION         = position;
            holder.TITLE            = (TextView)    convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.SUMMARY          = (TextView)    convertView.findViewById(R.id.summary);
            holder.DATE             = (TextView)    convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.CONTACT_ICON     = (ImageView)   convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.CONTACT_ICON.setTag(position);
            holder.OPTIONS_ICON     = (ImageView)   convertView.findViewById(R.id.options);         
            holder.OPTIONS_ICON.setFocusable(false);
            holder.OPTIONS_ICON.setTag(position);

            convertView.setTag(holder); 
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.CONTACT_ICON.setBackgroundDrawable(c_images.get(position)); 

        holder.TITLE.setText(item.TITLE);
        holder.SUMMARY.setText(item.SUMMARY);
        holder.SUMMARY.setMaxLines(2);
        holder.DATE.setText(item.DATE);   

        if (!MathUtils.isEven(position)){
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.darker));
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.medium_dark));
        }

        return convertView;
    }//end method

    static class ViewHolder {       
        TextView TITLE;
        TextView SUMMARY;
        TextView DATE;
        ImageView CONTACT_ICON;
        ImageView OPTIONS_ICON;
        int POSITION;
    }//end inner class
}//end class
```

Comment: call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter when you need to refresh listview

Comment: this will cause the entire ListView to update all it's views, triggering getView(), triggering AsyncTask, and so on.

Comment: How are you modifying convertView in AsyncRequest? Also, when you inflate it, use the inflate(R.layout.blank, parent, false) variant, so that it gets its LayoutParams set. 

Lastly, onProgressUpdate is meant for *progress updates*. If you need something to run at the end of the task, use *onPostExecute*.

Unless your data setting is really, really, really complicated, this is the wrong approach - you will inevitably end up with a task holding a reference to a recycled view and all hell *will* break loose.

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(View result) {
   super.onPostExecute(result);   
   result    = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.history_list_item_holo_dark, parent, false); And so on. Updated my code, silly mistake, thanks for the answer on that! Didn't work for my specific problem though :(

Comment: @dmmh - what are you trying to do exactly? convertView=result; just assigns the local reference to be result, there's no way on earth that would change the item in the ListView.

Again, post the code of AsyncRequest as I sincerely doubt it's complicated enough to warrant its own AsyncTask. What you're trying to do seems like a *really, really, *really** bad idea.

Comment: yeah, scratch that. Example updated, thanks for the help sofar!

Comment: I don't need to do it like this, if you have any better idea to perform long lasting operations like decrypting and update Views in my example, please feel free to suggest me some!

Comment: Please, comment if I understand your goals correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dmmh, what you say, you are wanting to do (So I need the ListView to update (add the item) only when progress is done) and what you are doing (AsyncTask in getView) are quite the opposite things.

AsyncTask in the end of getView is used (however in different way) for lazy image load i.e. to show large images and show text+imageplaceholder until download is complete.

You are trying to gradually fill in your adapter's datasourse in the First AsyncTask, but every time, you  notify observers about changes in dataset you will have another cycle of getView calls for every item in dataset. No good.

First, never, **NEVER!!!** assume that getView will supply you back a convertview, previously filled for this very position. So you MUST either refill convert view with new values, or turn off performance optimization and supply new view every time you are asked for it. There's no way for ListView to turn off recycling attempts because this is the essence of ListView, the feature it is build upon.

Second (resulted from first), **avoid at all means** storing time-expensive (or user input) data into your newly created Views only. Views come and go, and you do not want to walk the long way to get the expensive data (or just lose user input). The only partial exclusion are simple ineffective implementations of big image lazy loading. To reduce memory usage they download only images that are currently visible by user. More effective implementations use off-ListView caching.

So, if you really want to have the items in your ListView to be added one at a time, but in full glory, you should:

0*. If you have to load user-provided icons and this takes significant time to load (I have not understand your initial post about that) make an empty ArrayList to cache loaded ones and access them by index. If all images are already available by some index, ignore this matter.

```
class DecryptedRecord {
    String title                = "";
    String summary              = "";
    String date                 = "";
    int contactViewIndex        = -1;
    int contactOptionsIndex     = -1;
    int contactImageIndex       = -1;
    int typeImageIndex          = -1;
    int optionsImageIndex       = -1; //if option icon varies. ignore otherwise
}
```

1. Declare DecryptedRecord class, containing necessary data to fill in the view, e.g.:
2. In your AsyncTask: after loading every HistoryHolder, perform "heavy decrypting" and fill new DecryptedRecord with the values. If it is necessary to load cusom image(see no.0*), load it here and store its index in cache(ignore this if 0* is irrelevant). Attach filled DecryptedRecord to the HistoryHolder with setTag(). Call publishProgress(HistoryHolder)
3. In onProgressUpdate just add HistoryHolder to Adapter  and call historyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
4. In getView() **synchronously** inflate the view if convertView is null, and **IN ALL CASES**  populate it with the data from DecryptedRecord acqired from HistoryHolder.getTag(). Inclusive, call  setImageBitmap() on your ImageViews adressing necessary Bitmap in the corresponding list by index.

This should do what you want. Please, if you would have errors/problems, try to include complete code in your question, or it will be very difficult to understand the details of your situation. Hope that helps.

Comment: in fact they are not notified everytime, because there is a null check on the `getView()`. I do like some of your ideas, but ArrayAdapter is way to simple for my example, which has 3 icons and 3 TextViews (see HistoryHolder). Shouldn't really matter which adapter I use anyway, BaseAdapter should be just fine. I will fiddle around later tonight with some of the comments here and post back later today, or this week

Comment: Yes type of adapter is not of primary concern here(just using an abstraction before you've posted details), primary idea was to load bitmaps and save them into adapter's data source before calling notification change in onProgressUpdate, and then Inflate synchronously in getView

Comment: you are totally wrong, if you think that null check allows you to process only newly created view, and will stop recyling attempts from ListView when, say your list scrolls or adapts to datasource change. On the basis on details, you provided, I will edit the answer significantly.

Comment: you're right, ofcourse, but I am currently using `addItem()`, and not using `notifyDatasetChanged()`, so it doesn't lead to `getView()` getting called multiple times in my spcific case. Anyways, I am shifting away from my current code based on a combination of answers and tips here, will post back a solution soon(ish)

Comment: uhm it might lead to `getView()` getting called multiple times ofcourse, but in my case it ends there...Man I really should take a class to be able to explain myself in Java terms ;)

Comment: I am writing an answer... check it soon )

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate your concerns. Decrypting/decoding data has no place in the UI layer.

In general, your current approach to have AsyncTasks per item is difficult and (some would say) wrong for multiple reasons:

1. Honeycomb and above, there's only ever one AsyncTask running at any one point in time, unless you explicitly set the Executor.
2. More importantly, by holding a reference to `convertView`, you're leaking abstraction from the ListView - it's possible that the view you're holding a reference to is being reused for a different position. Unless you take painstaking care to cancel AsyncTasks and ensure proper result delivery, this **will** cause you trouble.
3. As mentioned above, decrypting/decoding data has no place in the UI layer (and I consider the Adapters UI layer, since they have similar constraints on execution speed).

If I were you, I'd use a memory cache of decrypted data, expanding/shrinking it as demand changes. Then, I would just fetch decrypted data in the `getView()` method of the adapter. In order to avoid decrypting items when scrolling, you can set up a scroll listener on the `ListView`, so that you only show the items when the list is not moving. There's a demo in ApiDemos that does something similar.

EDIT:
As for your obvious problem, you're reinflating a view (`result`) without adding it to the list item (the `convertView` field in the task). You can fix that by adding it to `convertView` (in an empty layout, for example). Again, this will not work as you expected in all cases.

Comment: I actually need to only run one AsyncTask at a time, so that's fine with me. I do like the memory cache approach. Gotto look into how this combines with my current approach, ie: the application isn't running at all times (using BroadcastReceiver's). Out of curiosity, I seem to be missing something obvious: how do I add `result` to `convertView`?

Comment: Well, make sure convertView is a layout, cast it to ViewGroup and call addView.

Comment: Thanks for the help man. Your post was very very helpfull. Based on it I decided to move away from the way data was presented to the UI. Basically my problem with setting the images was caused by the bad design choices I made previously. Now that I fixed this, there is no longer a need to asynchonously load the images.

I am gonna mark @alexei burmistrov 's answer as accepted, because it's a bit more detailed. Both answers lead to my current solution though, which is buttery fast!

Answer (score 1):

1. You could create a content provider which has your decoded data stored in a db/temp data structure and use that to update your views. The decoding etc could happen in a background via a service/thread. The adapter could talk to the decoded data via this provider. This is related to alexei burmistrov idea mentioned above.
2. Not the good option -  To use your current layout - a layout file that has both blank & filled layouts. When the layout is first shown, the blank view is visible. and when task is finished the visibility is set to gone.

This solution is not optimal as the asynctask would run each time a getView is called. And Android re-uses views so it could be many times based on how you scroll on the UI etc.

sample code:

```
    public void getView(){

    result      = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.history_list_item_holo_dark, parent, false);

    holder                  = new ViewHolder();
    holder.TITLE            = (TextView)    result .findViewById(R.id.title);
    holder.SUMMARY          = (TextView)    result .findViewById(R.id.summary);
    ..
    holder.OPTIONS_ICON.setTag(id); 

    result.setTag(holder);
    result.setTag(R.id.view_id ,id);

    AsyncTask.execute(result);
    convertView = result;

 }

    AsyncTask(View ...){
            onPostExecute(View view){
                     ViewHolder holder = view.getTag();
                    if(holder != null){
                            //set visibility of views in holder
                            //update Text & data
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: I despise Android's database handling, it's troublesome and a lot of work to achieve something relatively simple. Let's not get into selections, projections and the ugly methods here. Ugh. I am storing the values to plain old SharedPreferences. Which in itself presents it's own problems ofcourse :)

Answer (score 0):

First, when the async task runs the onPostExecute you will have to set the data to the adapter and notifydatasetchanged().
Now be a little more clean with the list view when is empty using something like creating a progressBar and set it to the listview like this:

```
listView.setEmptyView(progressbar);
```

Comment: thanks, but I am already doing that. The problem is not getting the data to the adapter in the right time, but for the views to visibly update as well. There's 2 AsyncTask's, one in the Activity, and one on the adapter. The adapter is getting data changes just fine, just not view changes. The other suggestion might come in handy though.